# Deploy ARM Template with Octopus Deploy in a Package

Tags: visual-studio, azure, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I have a created an ARM template in Visual Studio, and I need to package the JSON files so that I can use the option in Octopus Deploy to deploy the JSON files within the ARM template as a package - as described in the following link, under section **'Template Contained in a Package**

https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/azure-deployments/resource-groups

The problem is that I don't know what application in Visual Studio to package the application? I did some research and I read that the best package to use in nuspec as described here:

https://dinventive.com/blog/2016/10/20/5-steps-and-under-30-minutes-to-deploy-arm-templates-via-octopus-deploy/

However, there are a whole bunch of nuspec applications. The closet I got to what I need is the NuGetToolsPackager, as shown in the image.

[nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSIit.png)

However, if there are any other suggestions, they will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided shows how to create the package from a build server (in this case VSTS), which is the recommended way to go. Packaging + building should be orchestrated from a build server, and not from and IDE if possible :)

That said, one good way to do this from Visual Studio would be to add a dependency to [the OctopusTools package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctopusTools/) which will download `Octo.exe` during your build. Then you can add a post-build script that calls `Octo.exe pack` to create your package, and then `Octo.exe push` to push it to a repository.

Documentation for `Octo.exe pack`: https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/creating-packages/nuget-packages/using-octo.exe

Documentation for `Octo.exe push`: https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/pushing-packages